# No longer able to send message from iPhone to work email on Outlook 2016 but can send to others at the company

Tags: messages, ms-office, exchange, ios, iphone

I was able to send messages, or photos from my iPhone 7 to my work email address (Work email uses Outlook 2016 on Microsoft Exchange). I am no longer able to. But I can send to anyone else in the company. I am able to send from my work email to the same iPhone. I tried updating to iOS 11.1.1, but this did not resolve. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sending iMessages to an email address or are you talking about email? What do you mean by you aren't able, do you get an error message? How do you know it hasn't worked? [edit] your question (There's no such phone as iPhone 7s, so I've presumed you're talking about iPhone 7.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, my bad, Iphone 7 Plus. I'd originally been able to send text messages & photos using the built in Message (Imessage) app. to my work email address. No error message, it just does not show up, I checked my "clutter" (spam) folder, also. If I send the same to anyone else at out company it goes right through. I am guessing the issue is within my Outlook: checked all settings in outlook to ensure I did't have my phone blocked, or a rule to move the messages to a folder. Odd that I can send an email/message to the phone but not from my phone to my email.

Comment: Has your company recently imposed restrictions of outside domains?

Comment: No. I can send messages or photos directly to any employee in the company from my IPHONE. When sent to my email, they just do not arrive. Checked all Outlook settings to see if I somehow blocked myself with a "rule", checked all "spam" and "clutter" folders. Searched my entire inbox by name and subject line. They just don't arrive. Thanks for your response